# Crossplatform sound with Python standard library

Tags: python, audio

I have searched plenty to find an answer, I have seen winsound repeatedly but that is just for windows and other modules seem to all be outside of the standard library.

Is there a simple way to play a `.wav` or any sound file using something from the standard library that will work on most platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the information here:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/

You can see that there are some built in modules like `wave` and others which are probably way better and are also platform independent.

If you choose to go with external libraries, you can plenty options like `PyMedia`, `PySDL`, `wxPython` and many others.

For example, using `PyMedia`:

```
import pymedia.audio.sound as sound
f = wave.open('myFile.wav', 'rb')
snd = sound.Output( f.getframerate(), f.getnchannels(), sound.AFMT_S16_LE )
s = f.readframes( 300000 )
snd.play(s)
```

Comment: thanks I will give wave or one of the others a go. I just need a simple method to play a sound in Tkinter.

Comment: Updated with `PyMedia` example